# Eigenvector system with matrix on right side of equality

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a math paper which describes the following system as an eigenvector system.

$(D − W )v = λDv$

My linear algebra skills are rusty, but I thought an eigenvector system must be of this form:

$Av = λv$

Is there a way I can express the first equation in the form of the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is an invertible matrix, then you can multiply by $D^{-1}$ on both sides of the equation to get
$$D^{-1} (D - W)v = D^{-1} \lambda D v \\ (I - D^{-1} W)v = \lambda v.$$
Just set $A = I - D^{-1}W$ to get $Av = \lambda v$, and you're in the form you want.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at Generalized Eigenvalue Problems in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem). The starting point for several eigenvalue problems is $Av=\lambda v$. This implies that eigenvalues are roots of the polynomial $\det(A-\lambda I)$. The generalization is $Av=\lambda Bv$. In that case, the eigenvalues are roots of polynomial $\det(A-\lambda B)$. Your problem fall in the latter category.